# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Bypassing Strong Name Validation

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-signing, assembly-signing

In our pipeline, we are building a Windows application that uses delay signing. We are using **locbaml** (checked into source control) to create satellite resource DLLs, and it uses `Assembly.LoadFrom` but it gives this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXX.resources, Version=5.1.38.1, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

Added `bypassTrustedAppStrongNames` to the locbaml app config, tried `false` and `true`, but didn't help:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bypasstrustedappstrongnames-element

I don't think can I run `sn.exe -VR *,{publicKeyToken}` to make an exclusion, so how can I load an assembly with `Assembly.LoadFrom` which is delay signed on Azure DevOps?

Comment: if you add te dll like embedded resource and not like satellite dll

Comment: Actually I was able to create a command line task in the pipeline and call sn.exe to set the exclusion - I am surprised this worked!  Is there anyway to do this in code in case these permissions ever change on azure devops?  thanks

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\sn.exe" -Vr *,{MyPublicKey}